# How to insert values into numpy array with groupby summation

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I have an empty numpy array `a`, an array with values that should be inserted `v`, and array with indeces, where these values should be inserted `i`. I want to insert values from array `v` into array `a` using indeces `i`. It can be done by simply `a[i] = v` when values in `i` are unique.

How to do that if values in `i` have duplicates and I want to compute sum of duplicates?

In case of duplicate indeces in `i`, only the last occurence in `i` will be used:

```py
from numpy import *
a = zeros(5)
i = array([1, 1, 2, 3])
v = array([10, 20, 30, 40])
a[i] = v
print(a) # [ 0. 20. 30. 40.  0.]
```

A loop over `i` works, but it is slow:

```
for j1, j2 in enumerate(i):
    a[j2] += v[j1]
print(a) # [ 0. 30. 30. 40.  0.]
```

An algorithm with iterative search, use and removal of unique values in `i` is too complex for this simple task.

How to do this summation without a loop?

Answer (score 0):

A similar problem was here:
[Add multiple values to one numpy array index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41990028/add-multiple-values-to-one-numpy-array-index)

The answer is:

```
add.at(a, i, v)
```

Answer (score 0):

The proposed answer by @Anton is pretty good. You can also use `np.bincount` with weights which is a built in function for this purpose:

```
a = np.bincount(i,v,minlength=5)
#[ 0. 30. 30. 40.  0.]
```

Equivalent pandas groupby solution:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(v).groupby(i).sum()
a[df.index] = df.to_numpy().flatten()
#[ 0. 30. 30. 40.  0.]
```

You can also use `np.diff` or `np.searchsorted` to achieve this goal too. I find the above ones more readable.